# aws-sdk-ruby Aws::ACM::Client#import_certificate File paths or contents of files

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

I'm trying to use the `aws-sdk-ruby` to import Certificates to ACM. However, when I try to use the [`Aws::ACM::Client#import_certificate`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ACM/Client.html#import_certificate-instance_method) using either of the following methods, the stack trace tells me my private key is not 1024 or 2048. If that were the case Entrust wouldn't have signed my Certificate. I also told the `openssl` program to generate as 2048.

The Error Message

> The private key is not supported. Only RSA 1024-bit and 2048-bit private keys are allowed.

First code example

```
def acm_upload(options)
  require 'aws-sdk'
  @aws_region = ENV['AWS_REGION'] || ENV['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] || 'us-west-2'
  @aws_profile = ENV['AWS_PROFILE'] || ENV['AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE'] || 'default'

  acm = Aws::ACM::Client.new(region: @aws_region, profile: @aws_profile)
  begin
    puts '=> Uploading Key, Cert, and Chain to ACM.'
    aws_response = acm.import_certificate({
      certificate: options[:cert_name],
      private_key: options[:key_name],
      certificate_chain: options[:chain_name],
    })
  rescue Aws::ACM::Errors::ServiceError => e
    puts 'An AWS ACM Service Error has occured.'
    raise e.message
  rescue Aws::Errors::ServiceError => e
    puts 'An AWS Error has occured.'
    raise e.message
  end

  puts aws_response
end

acm_upload({
  cert_name: './ssl/certificate/signed_cert.crt',
  key_name: './ssl/key/private_key.pem',
  chain_name: './ssl/chains/cert_chain.crt'
})
```

The first method call says my key is not 2048bit. Then the second method also does as well:

```
acm_upload({
  cert_name: File.read('./ssl/certificate/signed_cert.crt'),
  key_name: File.read('./ssl/key/private_key.pem'),
  chain_name: File.read('./ssl/chains/cert_chain.crt)'
})
```

Same error as above. The documentation isn't very clear to me on what its expecting. It says data, and I figured that was the contents of the certificate file. Has anyone else had this issue before?

I was able to upload the key, certificate, and chain to ACM using the `aws` Python CLI that they provide using `file://`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the AWS CLI and see if that works for you:

```
aws acm import-certificate --certificate file://certificate.crt --private-key file://private_key.key --certificate-chain file://certificate_chain.crt
```

aws --version

note: compatible with version: aws-cli/1.14.18 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.8.22

note: NOT compatible with version: aws-cli/1.10.21 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.4.12

Comment: I was able to upload the key, certificate, and chain to ACM using the aws Python CLI that they provide using file://.